# How to decompose a matrix into its orthogonal and diagonal parts (assuming it has that form)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $A = U * S$ for $U$ orthogonal and $S$ diagonal, ordered and positive.

If I only know $A$, is it possible to obtain $U$ and $S$?

My first guess would be taking the singular value decomposition, since $U * D * I = A$ by construction, but, due to the non-uniqueness of the SVD, I don't know how to enforce this specific solution.

Comment: Isn't the diagonal of S just composed of the norms of the columns of A?

Comment: You are correct, sorry for not noticing that before.

Comment: Darsh's comment solves your problem, but it looks like you could need the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn Darsh Rajan's comment into an answer:

if $A = US$ with $U$ orthogonal, $S$ diagonal, then $A^TA = S^TU^TUS = S^2$, so we know $S^2$ (and this gives us a condition on which matrices can be expressed in this way). If we further assume $S$ is positive, then we can find $S$ uniquely, and so find $U = AS^{-1}$.